# voltage comparator always on

Tags: voltage, transistors, comparator

I'm using a LM339 voltage comparator by supplying it 5V, with a reference voltage of 1V.  I have a 3K pull up resistor on the output to 5V.  For some reason, the output voltage is always 2V.  It doesn't change at all when my input signal rises above the 1V reference voltage.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated :)

[image: LM339]

Edit:  I wasn't clear in the diagram, but the bottom phototransistor is actually attached to a voltage regulator.  Also, I tried removing the top photodiode and now the output is always 5V.  I think it's like this because I have to pull it high to Vcc so I'm not sure how to make this work.

Comment: Decent description, but I think you should post the schematic. Is your Vref on the inverting input?

Comment: Okay I will, and yes it is.

Comment: @Haley  (1) Please read: [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics).  (2) It's always good to link the datasheet for the parts that you are using.  That saves time and clicks.  Folks out here appreciate that.

Comment: Thank you, what program do you use for making schematics?

Comment: @Haley  Altium (which you seem to be using) would do just fine.  Even paper and pencil will do.  The issue is more with good schematic habits, rather than capture software per se.

Comment: What signal are you connecting to the free end of the photodiode?  Be aware that the LM339 has PNP input transistors so the bias current will tend to pull the input to the positive rail.

Comment: Have you looked at the output signal with a scope?  Is it oscillating or a 60Hz signal due to pickup?

Comment: Is the symbol you are using meant to represent the physical layout - if so it is not correct as pin 8 is right across from  pin 7 in the package. The pins count down one side of the package then up the other.

Comment: @KevinWhite Sorry for the confusion, but the bottom photodiode is actually a IR receiver, connected to a voltage regulator.  It increases in voltage as it gets closer to the IR emitter.  At a fixed distance, the signal does not oscillate.  Also, the diagram is not the physical layout, I connected it like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect photodiode o/p to I/V converter and then assign it to non-inv pin of comparator. Measure i/v converter output and accordingly verify LM339 o/p is changing or not.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple resistor be an I/V converter, or do you mean using an op amp I/V circuit with a DAC?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier#/media/File:TIA_simple.svg                 refer above schematic, By changing Rf,you can vary output voltage above and below reference ( in your case 1v)

Answer (score 3):

As long as the anode of the photodiode is not connected, the input will not be driven to any particular voltage. Simply reading the voltage across the diode does not mean that it will be seen as such by the circuit.

Ground the anode.

Edit - Sorry, but I got turned around. The cathode should be grounded, and the anode tied to the comparator. Alternatively, provide a reference voltage greater than 1 volt, and connect the anode to that.

Comment: The the cathode will go negative when there is light.  A resistor from the cathode to the positive supply would work.  Select the resistor depending upon the desired sensitivity.

Comment: Sorry, my diagram wasn't very clear.  The bottom photodiode is actually connected to a voltage regulator.  Are you talking about the top or bottom photodiode?

Comment: The top diode is an LED as shown in your diagram (the arrows go away from the device).  The bottom device has the arrows going into the device and so I assumed it was a Photodiode. What voltage is the regulator?

Answer (score 1):

It truly sounds as if you don't have the ground pin connected properly.

You are aware that the pinout of the LM339 is NOT the standard quad op-amp pinout?

Vcc is pin 3; Ground is pin 12.  The 4 output pins are pins 1, 2, 13, 14.

Comment: I just uploaded a schematic, and GND is connected correctly